# Exaggerating colors in GIMP/Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, gimp

I have images such as the one below from which I need to count the prominent white spots. Unfortunately my object counting algorithm is becoming confused due to those "fuzzy" white areas. It can sometimes see hundreds of objects there.

[image: example image]

So what I'm wondering is whether there's some way to perhaps exaggerate the white spots and suppress the "fuzzy" areas either using filters in GIMP or Python libraries.

Thank you!

Comment: You can threshold them: e.g. everything with lightness over 127 is white, below is black.

Comment: I'm aware of thresholding and contrast options, I was hoping there was something more flexible. For example, some of the spots aren't as bright as others and thus are excluded. For a more specific example, those ones at the very bottom are not there anymore if I try to threshold out the fuzzy cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using G'MIC's Bilateral Filtering, it was the perfect tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the [contrast](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-brightness-contrast.html) in GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an [**adaptive threshold**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm).

The modules that I know have this in Python are [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_threshold_adaptive.html) and [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html).